# Show short description under product title on mini cart

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

my client want to show short description under mini cart title:

You can see image screenshot:

[image]

I used  `grep` command found it coming from :`/vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/DefaultItem.php`

and using html template file from: `/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html`

so i have passed short description from `DefaultItem.php` to Ajax response show short description and Same changes on html template file `default.html` also but not reflecting on front.

i have cleared caches, deployed content and tried on private browser but still not working.

Comment: Please check it in private browser or clear Local Storage from the browser and then check it,

Comment: please attach code how to pass description and how to display description in html file

Comment: Have you do what I say?

Comment: Please load the site in browser & check in network tab with pub file path "default.html" and open it. Has it the code for short desc ? If no, add directly inside it and save. check if it is work. you also don't need to run command as you are working in pub file path directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override this file

```
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/DefaultItem.php
```

and add call sort description value here like below

```
/**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function doGetItemData()
    {
        $imageHelper = $this->imageHelper->init($this->getProductForThumbnail(), 'mini_cart_product_thumbnail');
        $productName = $this->escaper->escapeHtml($this->item->getProduct()->getName());

        return [
            'options' => $this->getOptionList(),
            'qty' => $this->item->getQty() * 1,
            'item_id' => $this->item->getId(),
            'configure_url' => $this->getConfigureUrl(),
            'is_visible_in_site_visibility' => $this->item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility(),
            'product_id' => $this->item->getProduct()->getId(),
            'product_name' => $productName,
            'product_sku' => $this->item->getProduct()->getSku(),
            'sort_description'=>'sort_description',
            'product_url' => $this->getProductUrl(),
            'product_has_url' => $this->hasProductUrl(),
            'product_price' => $this->checkoutHelper->formatPrice($this->item->getCalculationPrice()),
            'product_price_value' => $this->item->getCalculationPrice(),
            'product_image' => [
                'src' => $imageHelper->getUrl(),
                'alt' => $imageHelper->getLabel(),
                'width' => $imageHelper->getWidth(),
                'height' => $imageHelper->getHeight(),
            ],
            'canApplyMsrp' => $this->msrpHelper->isShowBeforeOrderConfirm($this->item->getProduct())
                && $this->msrpHelper->isMinimalPriceLessMsrp($this->item->getProduct()),
        ];
    }
```

And override this file in your theme

```
/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html
```

and add below code in file

```
<div class="sort-description" data-bind="html:sort_description"></div>
```

You will sure get description in minicart

Comment: i think your did not get my problem, i have already done same way but not reflecting.

Comment: what code you write for sort description value call ? @ShivSingh

Comment: That is correct and i can see on Ajax response. screenshot: https://prnt.sc/ql7kv9

Comment: and what code you write in html file ?@ShivSingh

Comment: <!-- ko if: product_short_desc -->
<p data-bind="text: product_short_desc" class="mini-cart-short-desc"></p>
<!-- /ko -->

Comment: Fixed now by: setup:static-content:deploy -f and by the way its not help to me but i will accept it as correct answer so it will help to others :)

Answer (score 0):

How can I get the value of short description instead a text line "sort-description"?

Thanks.